# Tag the Smash Brothers Questions!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[image]

Comment: Is there any possibility of increasing the maximum tag name length?

Comment: @Strix [Not](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1037/increase-tag-length-limit-to-30-characters "The tags, and you can see my 26 letter plight in the comments too!") [a](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-to-tag-use-acronyms-or-not/95#95 "Jeff's only comment on my answer") [chance](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8/tagging-suggestions/1038#1038 "This doesn't actually say anything on it, but the answer was in response to the request I first linked anyway")

Comment: That is an unfortunately awful and stubborn stance for him to take.

Comment: @Strix In his defense, we're the only site that really runs into this as a frequent problem. In all other respects, it's typically more useful to use short words and simple terms for tagging, which the limit helps enforce. It suggests grouping concepts more readily than trying to, say, tag every kind of error. Maximum tag length could be non-trivial to change.

Comment: @Strix @Grace increasing tag length would indeed be a difficult change and have performance implications because of the way tags are denormalized into a single column right now (unfortunately)

Comment: @Juan Aww... it was a joke-type thingy. But, understood.

Comment: @Grace, I know -- mine too, hence the mocking of your signature... rollback if you want, rollback like crazy!

Comment: @Juan Nah, I've got a better idea. You'll see when I get home tonight. ♪

Comment: I'm afraid now...

Comment: +1 for awesome Status Completed.

Comment: That Completed threw me off for a complete loop for a few seconds.

Comment: -1 needs more victory tune.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I saw `ssb-brawl`, I'm not sure I'd know what game it refers to.  I'd prefer shortening by removing "super" or shortening "brothers" to "bros".  I think either of these are pretty unambiguous:

`super-smash-bros-melee`
`super-smash-bros-brawl`

or

`smash-brothers-melee`
`smash-brothers-brawl`

"Bros" is probably preferred, since that seems to be Nintendo's preferred way of writing the name (for example, see http://www.smashbros.com/en_us/index.html)

Comment: I think it's actually stylized as "Bros" on the packaging.

Comment: @StrixVaria Ah, great point.  They seem to use "bros" everywhere (even their domain name): http://www.smashbros.com/en_us/index.html

Comment: I think the first two tags work well, as the difference between "smash bros" and "smash brothers" is hardly ambiguous.

Comment: Agreeing with this solution. It's unambiguous and will still direct people to use the proper tag, whereas `ssb-brawl` wouldn't be what people would start typing in to tag their question.

Comment: I stated this in my edit summary, but in conjunction with this I'm also switching `super-smash-brothers` to `super-smash-bros`, and applying a synonym. This keeps a consistency so that all 3 show up the same. Nice work, and thanks to @Strix for doing some of the retagging.